# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app with angular js and phonegap.

I am using jquery mobile in a directive, it is for adding some animation to a notification bar. I t works well with jquery 1.8.1 but when I use jquery mobile

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:26

(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:26
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:27
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:22
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:24
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of jQuery are using? for jQuery-Mobile 1.3.1, it's recommended to use jQuery 1.8.3 and higher.

Comment: @Omar actually you made me fix that by your comment, I left commented out:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With *jQuery-Mobile version 1.3.1*, use *jQuery version 1.8.3* or higher. It's recommended to use **jQuery version 1.9.1**.

Comment: It might be obvious, but tripped me up, include the jQuery script before jQuery mobile, otherwise you'll continue to see that error and what WTF is going on.

Comment: @Josh exactly, jQuery should be loaded before jQuery Mobile. Also, changing global settings code should be placed before JQM.

Comment: Thanks. saved much time

Answer (score 6):

@Omar actually you made me fix that by your comment, I left commented out:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I added it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Include first Jquery, then Jquery-mobile, like this:

```
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, as others stated, use a jquery version 1.9.1 or higher.